# My function skip my if then else statement

Tags: javascript

i have this function that scan over 9 elements. i've been troubleshooting for over 4 hours now. the problem is that i want the alert box appear just once if it detects a "none" value from one of the elements.and another one is that when one of the elements is not equal to "none" the other elements ignore this statement:

```
                  if (obj.value == "none"){
                      alert("You must specify the item's size!");      
                  }
```

Here is the whole function:

```
function swapImage(id,primary,secondary) {
     src=document.getElementById(id).src;


    if (src.match(primary)) {


                  var arr = new Array();
                  arr = document.getElementsByName('jumpMenu');

                  alert("total objects with name \"jumpMenu\" = \n" + arr.length);

                  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                  {
                      var obj = document.getElementsByName('jumpMenu').item(i);
                    //   alert(obj.id + " =  " + obj.value);

                       if (obj.value == "none"){    

                          alert("You must specify the item's size!");      
                      }  

                      else
                      {   

                      document.getElementById(id).src=secondary;     

                      }
                }
    }
    else 
    {
      location.href='blog.php';
    }
  }
```

its quite long coz i have 9 of them, so ill just insert here one of the elements:

```
<table width="200" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <th width="63">Price:</th>
            <th width="127"> <?php echo $final_array[0][1]; ?></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>         
            <th>Size:</th>
            <form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="blog.php">
            <th><select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" class="hirap">
                <option value ="none">Enter Item Size</option>
                <option value ="S">6</option>
                <option value ="M">8</option>
                <option value ="L">10</option>
                <option value ="XL">12</option>
                <option value ="XXL">14</option>
              </select>
            </th>
            <th><img
                    id="tadi"
                    onclick="swapImage(
                      'tadi',
                      'images/submit.gif',
                      'images/so.gif'
                    )"                      
                    src="images/submit.gif"
                    title="View Order"
                  />            

          </th>
            </form>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. Please don't add tags that don't match the question.

Comment: i have included it on the question

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: ahm i dont know console..ahm i am using netbeans

Comment: oh sorry..i did change the name of the function earlier..haha dont know why i did that sorry..

Comment: sorry i didnt notice thought it was just a tag.sory im just a beginner here in satckoverflow

Comment: it still skips the if then else when the first jumpMenu is not equal to "none"

Comment: well thats my problem..glad you seee it

Answer (score 1):

It's not immediately clear to me what is 'valid' data. Which one of the following describes valid data for you?

1. all menus should have a value other than `none` selected, (so `6`, `10`, `8`, `none`, `6` would be invalid but `6`, `10`, `8`, `12`, `6` would be valid)
2. at least one menu should have a value other than `none` selected (so `6`, `10`, `8`, `none`, `6` would be valid but `none`, `none`, `none`, `none`, `none` would be invalid).

For case 1, introduce a variable that records whether all sizes have been specified, and if they have, do the necessary at the end of the loop:

```
            var allOkay = true;
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                var obj = document.getElementsByName('jumpMenu').item(i);
                //   alert(obj.id + " =  " + obj.value);

                if (obj.value === "none"){    

                    alert("You must specify the item's size!");      
                    allOkay = false;
                    break;
                }  
            }

            if (allOkay)
            {
                document.getElementById(id).src=secondary;
            }
```

The variable `allOkay` specifies whether all of the menus we've checked so far have a value other than `none` selected.  We set it to `true` at the start of the loop, as at this point we haven't found any menus with `none` selected.

Then, if we find a menu where `none` is selected, we show the alert, and record that we've now found a menu with `none` selected by setting `allOkay` to `false`.  We also `break`, which exits the `for` loop.  There's no point going any further; once we've found a menu with its value set to `none` we may as well stop.

At the end of the loop the variable `allOkay` will record whether all menus have a value selected other than `none`.

It seems likely to me that you would only want the line `document.getElementById(id).src=secondary;` to run if the alert box was not shown.  In that case, the best place to put it is after the loop, and only run it if all of the menus had values other than `none` selected.

Case 2 is similar.  In this case, we keep track of whether all of the menus we've found so far are set to `none`, and if so, report a message at the end of the loop:

```
            var allNone = true;
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                var obj = document.getElementsByName('jumpMenu').item(i);
                //   alert(obj.id + " =  " + obj.value);

                if (obj.value !== "none"){    

                    document.getElementById(id).src=secondary;
                    allNone = false;
                    break;
                }  
            }

            if (allNone)
            {
                alert("You must specify the item's size!");
            }
```

Comment: ahm i tried the first case and the result was even i had chosen a value not "none" it still prompt the alert message. while in the second case it work when i choose not "none" to one element but the problem is that the other elements change icon too.

Comment: @MArioSiAko: It is still *very unclear* what you are asking.  I'm still not absolutely sure which of the two cases above fits your situation.  Can you also please explain *exactly* what you mean by 'the other elements change icon too'?

Comment: ok this is what my web page looks like, ahm there is a 1 dropdown menu and a submit icon beside it, the dropdown menu is the one we are taking about. it has the numbers and "none" options. so if you choose one of the numbers, and you click the submit icon beside it, the icon will be change by new icon but if the option is "none" it will not be able to change to new icon and a alert messagebox will appear and that is "You must specify the item's size".so either of the cases meets what i want..

Comment: i have 9 dropdown menu and all of the option of each menu has "none",6,8,10,12, and 14..hope this makes you understand..tnx for the patience

Comment: @MArioSiAko: By saying "there is a 1 drop down menu" and then "i have 9 dropdown menu" you are contradicting yourself.  Or do you have 9 submit buttons as well?  One for each menu?  In that case, what should each individual submit button do?  Should it only check the menu in the same row?

Comment: ahm i have 9 dropdown menu and one submit button in each dropdown menu..the submit button will save the data from that menu if click and will be replace by another button.the case is that it can only be change by another button if the option from the dropdown menu that was chosen is not the "none" option..

Comment: @MArioSiAko: I completely don't understand what you are describing. 'it can only be change by another button' - what's "it"?  What's "another button"?  I simply don't know what you're trying to do, and the fact that nobody else has answered suggests that nobody else on SO has a clue what you want either.  **If you cannot explain CLEARLY what you are trying to do in one or two further comments I'm afraid I will have no option other than to delete this answer and give up helping you.**

Comment: sorry.ok ill try it to fiddle so you can understand it better..sorry

Answer (score 0):

to all that tried to help me..thank you very much i had solve it..here the solution for my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swapImage(id, primary, secondary,ide) {
src = document.getElementById(id).src;

if (src.match(primary)) {

    var allNone = true;

    var arr = new Array();

    arr = document.getElementById(ide);
  //  alert(arr.value +"asd"+ arr.length);

    for(var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i-=1) {

        // var obj = arr.getElementsByName('jumpMenu').item(i);

        // alert(obj.value);

       if (arr.value != "none"){    

                document.getElementById(id).src=secondary;
                allNone = false;
                break;
            }  
    }
      if (allNone)
        {
            alert("You must specify the item's size!");
        }

} else {
    location.href = 'blog.php';
}
```

}